# reload rubymotion view controller and refresh Teacup layout

Tags: ios, layout, rubymotion

I'm troubled to find a way to reload the variables in the labels within the layout when the 'redo' button is pushed. I'm using ProMotion and Teacup layout. The 'yes' button works. How can I reload the controller and refresh the layout?

```
class MoodController < UIViewController
  stylesheet :mood

  layout :mood do
    @label = subview UILabel, :label

    @subject_label = subview UILabel, :subject_label
    @verb_label    = subview UILabel, :verb_label
    @object_label  = subview UILabel, :object_label

    @redo_button = subview(UIButton, :redo_button)
    @yes_button  = subview(UIButton, :yes_button)
  end

  def layoutDidLoad
     self.title = "Normal Navbar"

     @redo_button.addTarget( self, action:'redo', 
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside)

     @yes_button.addTarget( self, action:'yes', 
        forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside)
  end

  def yes
    @yes_pushed = ResultsController.new
    self.navigationController << @yes_pushed
  end

  def redo
    @redo_pushed = MoodController.new
    self.navigationController << @redo_pushed
  end
end
```

Comment: Abstract out your setup code? What exactly are you trying to "Refresh"?

Comment: This isn't a ProMotion screen. Are you using ProMotion somewhere else?

Comment: Somehow I got this to work, though it hasn't made any money for us yet.